# Minimum distance between a surface and a point

Tags: 3d, maxima-minima

I created this problem which is inspired by some problems I encountered in this site.

What is the minimum distance between point $(1,1,1)$ and a surface defined by $z-xy=10$?

The answer is $\sqrt{18}$ but I am curious how others solve this kind of problem.

Comment: The title mentions a lattice but there's no lattice in the question statement.

Comment: What i meant is a point with integer coordinates, i edited it out to avoid misleading title.

Comment: If $Q(u,v,w)$ is the closest point on the surface to the point $P(1,1,1)$, then $\overrightarrow{PQ}=(u-1,v-1,w-1)$ is parallel to the normal to the surface at $Q$, which is the gradient of $z-xy-10$ at $(x,y,z)=(u,v,w)$.  The gradient is $(-v,-u,1)$.  So you have to solve $$(u-1,v-1,w-1)=\lambda(-v,-u,1)$$ for $\lambda,u,v,w$ such that $w-uv=10$.

Comment: Nice, could You post a detailed answer as well?

Comment: I am not sure which level of solutions you are looking for.  Do your students know multi-variable/vector calculus or Lagrange multipliers?  The solution by joriki is practically the same as mine, except that I used the vector calculus approach.  Both our solutions have to deal with essentially the same system of equations.  But as far as elementary solutions are concerned, I couldn't think of anything better than mathlove's solution.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool I want to create a problem which is easier to solve by junior high schooler than by college students. My idea is, college student learned about lagrange, so that will be what first pop up in their mind, so i need to make lagrange solution harder than elementary solution. And i am wondering is this problem like that, hence the bounty. Also curious if there is other solutions.

Comment: Unfortunately I think the Lagrange-multipliers solution is actually easier.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool my elementary solution is slightly different from Mathlove. I still think elementary solution is easier, but maybe i am biased since i want it that way. I will post my answer too later. Still waiting for other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a compilation of ways I think solved the problem.  In solutions 2 and 3, there is an inherent assumption that a minimizing point exists.  However, this is due to the fact that the surface $z-xy=10$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R^3$.  For an interactive 3d plot, see [here](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/huubdwnn).

1. As in mathlove's solution, we want to minimize $$D(x,y,z)=\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2}$$ subject to $z=xy+10$.  That is, we want to minimize $$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+\big((xy+10)-1\big)^2=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(xy+9)^2.$$  However $$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(xy+9)^2=(x+y-1)^2+(xy+8)^2+18\ge 18.$$  The equality holds iff $x$ and $y$ are the roots of the polynomial $t^2-t-8$ (and since $z=xy+10$, we must have $z=(-8)+10=2$ at the minimizing point), which gives $$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{33}}{2},\frac{1\mp\sqrt{33}}{2},2\right).$$  At this point $D(x,y,z)=\sqrt{18}$.
2. This is a vector calculus/geometric solution.  Define $\varphi(x,y,z)=z-xy-10$.  If $Q(u,v,w)$ is a point on the surface given by $\varphi(x,y,z)=0$ that is the closest to $P(1,1,1)$, then $\overrightarrow{PQ}=(u-1,v-1,w-1)$ is parallel to $\nabla\varphi(u,v,w)$.  Since $\nabla\varphi(x,y,z)=(-y,-x,1)$, we get $$(u-1,v-1,w-1)=\lambda(-v,-u,1)$$ for some $\lambda\in \Bbb R$.  Since $Q$ is on the surface $\varphi(x,y,z)=0$, we get $w=uv+10$.  We note that $u\ne v$.  Otherwise, $w=uv+10=u^2+10\ge 10$, so that $|PQ|\geq |w-1|\geq |10-1| =9$, but the point $R(3,-3,1)$ on the surface is only at distance $$\sqrt{(3-1)^2+\big((-3)-1\big)^2+(1-1)^2}=2\sqrt5<9$$ away from $P$.  Now, $$\lambda(u-v)=(-\lambda v)-(-\lambda u)=(u-1)-(v-1)=u-v.$$  As $u\ne v$, we get $\lambda=1$.  Hence, $w-1=\lambda\cdot 1=1$, so $w=2$ and $uv=w-10=-8$.  Furthermore, $$u+v=\big((u-1)-(-\lambda v)\big)+1=0+1=1.$$  Therefore, $u$ and $v$ are the roots of $t^2-t-8$.  That is, $$(u,v,w)=\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{33}}{2},\frac{1\mp\sqrt{33}}{2},2\right),$$ so $|PQ|=\sqrt{18}$.
3. The square of the distance from an arbitrary point $(x,y,xy+10)$ on the surface $z-xy=10$ to $(1,1,1)$ is $$\delta(x,y)=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+\big((xy+10)-1\big)^2=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(xy+9)^2.$$  If $Q(u,v,uv+10)$ is closest to $(1,1,1)$, then $$\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial x}(u,v)=\frac{\partial\delta}{\partial y}(u,v)=0.$$  That is, $$u-1+v(uv+9)=v-1+u(uv+9)=0.$$  Therefore $$(u-v)(uv+8)=\big(v-1+u(uv+9)\big)-\big(u-1+v(uv+9)\big)=0.$$ As in the previous solution, we know that $u\ne v$.  Hence $uv+8=0$ or $uv=-8$.  That is $$u+v-1=u-1+v(uv+9)=0,$$ so $u+v=1$. The rest is as before, and we conclude that the minimizing points are $$(u,v,uv+10)=\left(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{33}}{2},\frac{1\mp\sqrt{33}}{2},2\right).$$  At this point $\sqrt{\delta(u,v)}=\sqrt{18}$.

[image: 3D Plot]

Comment: Exactly the same answer with me for the elementary solution. Lagrange is similar as well.

Answer (score 2):

We want to minimize 
$$\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(xy+10-1)^2}$$
which can be written as
$$\begin{align}&\sqrt{x^2-2x+1+y^2-2y+1+x^2y^2+18xy+81}
\\\\&=\sqrt{(y^2+1)x^2+(18y-2)x+y^2-2y+83}
\\\\&=\sqrt{(y^2+1)\bigg(x^2+\frac{18y-2}{y^2+1}x\bigg)+y^2-2y+83}
\\\\&=\sqrt{(y^2+1)\bigg(\bigg(x+\frac{9y-1}{y^2+1}\bigg)^2-\bigg(\frac{9y-1}{y^2+1}\bigg)^2\bigg)+y^2-2y+83}
\\\\&=\sqrt{(y^2+1)\bigg(x+\frac{9y-1}{y^2+1}\bigg)^2-\frac{(9y-1)^2}{y^2+1}+y^2-2y+83}
\\\\&=\sqrt{(y^2+1)\bigg(x+\frac{9y-1}{y^2+1}\bigg)^2+\frac{(y^2-y-8)^2}{y^2+1}+18}\end{align}$$

So, the minimum distance is $\color{red}{3\sqrt{2}}$ which is attained when
$$x+\frac{9y-1}{y^2+1}=y^2-y-8=0\quad \text{and}\quad z=xy+10$$
i.e.
$$(x,y)=\bigg(\frac{1\pm\sqrt{33}}{2},\frac{1\mp\sqrt{33}}{2},2\bigg)$$

Comment: can You elaborate on how You get $(x,y)$ from the last equation?

Comment: @Rezha Adrian Tanuharja: From $y^2-y-8=0$, you can get $y=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{33}}{2}$. Then, you can get $x,z$ from $x=-\frac{9y-1}{y^2+1}$ and $z=xy+10$.

Comment: excellent, thank You.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you rewrite the expression under the square root as $$(x+y-1)^2+(xy+8)^2+18.$$

Answer (score 2):

mathlove’s answer takes a better approach for this case; but you may not always be so fortunate as to be able to express one variable in terms of the others and to express the objective function in terms of squares that can be set to zero – here’s a general method that doesn’t rely on these features.

We want to minimize $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2$ subject to the constraint $z-xy=10$. Thus we need to find the stationary points of $f(x,y,z)=(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2+\lambda(z-xy-10)$, where $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier.

The partial derivatives are

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&=&2(x-1)-\lambda y\stackrel!=0\;,\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&=&2(y-1)-\lambda x\stackrel!=0\;,\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}&=&2(z-1)+\lambda\stackrel!=0\;.\\
\end{eqnarray}

These equations correspond to what WE Tutorial School derived in a comment based on geometrical considerations.

If $\lambda\ne-2$, the first two equations are a non-singular system of linear equations for $x,y$ in terms of $\lambda$. Since they are symmetrical with respect to $x$ and $y$, we can set $x=y$ and solve either of them to obtain $x=y=\frac2{2-\lambda}$. The third one allows us to express $z$ in terms of $\lambda$, with $z=1-\frac\lambda2$.

Now we can determine $\lambda$ from the constraint: $1-\frac\lambda2-\left(\frac2{2-\lambda}\right)^2=10$. According to [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%201%2B%5Cfrac%5Clambda2-%5Cleft%28%5Cfrac2%7B2-%5Clambda%7D%5Cright%29%5E2%3D10&dataset=) there is one real solution,

$$
\lambda=\frac13\left(-14-200\sqrt[3]{\frac2{2027-3\sqrt{12081}}}-2^\frac23\sqrt[3]{2027-3\sqrt{12081}}\right)\approx-18.020\;,
$$

which corresponds to $x=y\approx0.0999$ and $z\approx10.010$. The distance at this point is $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2}\approx9.099$.

If $\lambda=-2$, the first two equations are identical and yield $x+y=1$. Here $z=1-\frac\lambda2=2$, and we can determine $x$ and $y$ from the constraint: $2-xy=10$ and thus (with $x+y=1$) we have $2-x(1-x)=10$, with solution $x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{33}}2$ and accordingly $y=\frac{1\mp\sqrt{33}}2$. Here the distance is $\sqrt{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2)}=3\sqrt2\approx4.243$. Thus this stationary point is closer to $(1,1,1)$, and the minimum distance is $3\sqrt2$.

Comment: You can eliminate the case $x=y$ easily.  If $x=y$, then $z-xy=10$ implies that $$z=10+xy=10+x^2\ge 10.$$  Therefore the distance from $(x,y,z)$ to $(1,1,1)$ is at least $|10-1|=9$.  But the point $(3,-3,1)$ is only at the distance $\sqrt{2^2+(-4)^2}=2\sqrt{5}<9$ away from $(1,1,1)$.  Therefore a minimizing point cannot have $x=y$.  Hence you are left with the case $\lambda=-2$.